# How does Matematica compute the CDF of the binomial distribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, implementation-details

I want to know, how *Mathematica* actually implements the cumulative distribution function of the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). Which algorithm does *Mathematica* use to compute `CDF[BinomialDistribution[n, p], x]`? Does *Mathematica* use the [normal approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem), or does it use [a better approximation](http://www.unomaha.edu/wwwmath/OurArchive/KerriganMinigrants/2009_2010/2009_2010/BeichenWang_KRMP10.pdf)?

So far I have found the sites about [`BinomialDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinomialDistribution.html) and [`CDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CDF.html) but I haven't found an answer to my question there. I know that *Mathematica* is closed source but is there a way get information about the actual used algorithm?

Note: I never have used *Mathematica* before.

Comment: It evaluates the regularized incomplete beta function, which is built-in as `BetaRegularized[]`, for appropriate arguments. As to what algorithm is being used to evaluate that… the docs only note that it uses hypergeometric function representations and continued fractions under the hood, and nothing more.

Comment: You can see the use of [BetaRegularized](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BetaRegularized.html) just by evaluating `CDF[BinomialDistribution[n, p], x]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[J.M.'s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) comment:

> It evaluates the regularized incomplete beta function, which is built-in as `BetaRegularized[]`, for appropriate arguments. As to what algorithm is being used to evaluate that… [the docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#22073) only note that it uses hypergeometric function representations and continued fractions under the hood, and nothing more.

Comment: For what it is worth, Mathematica usually prefers slow and accurate over fast and approximate.